# Do these monads on Rel compose?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

$Rel$ is the category of sets and relations.

The cyclic list monad, $\mathcal{Cy}=(Cy, \mu_c, \eta_c)$ is defined as follows:

$Cy : Rel \rightarrow Rel$,
such that, $Cy(X)$ is all cyclic lists on the set X.  A cyclic list is just like a list except every element points to it's following element, and every element has exactly one predecessor pointing in. So the list forms a cycle or circle.
$\mu_c : Cy \cdot Cy \rightarrow Cy$
such that a cyclic list of cyclic lists maps to all cyclic lists found by breaking the internal lists in all ways possible and concatenating the resulting flattened lists.

We know that multiset is a monad, $\mathcal{Mu}$ on $Rel$.

I would like to know if the following composition is also a monad on $Rel$.

$\mathcal{Cy} \cdot \mathcal{Mu}$

This is cyclic lists of multisets.